# Why would a HTML page have a class of ‘javascript’?

Tags: javascript, html

Why would a HTML page have a class of ‘javascript’?

Comment: why would you ask a question with no context?

Comment: What RPM is saying (and why you got downvoted) is this: Provide a link to the page (and maybe the relevant line).

Comment: How did this incomprehensible mess of a question get 3 upvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common practice for a page to degrade gracefully in case JavaScript is disabled. For example, instead of a JavaScript slider you may want to present a combo box, or extra submit buttons. This may be required for accessibility and compatibility.
One way of doing so it to load the page ready for JavaScript-disabled clients, and use JavaScript to add a class to the `<body>` element (or other elements). CSS rules can use this class to change the look of the page - when you *know* JavaScript is enabled (after you've just run it), you can hide these controls, and rely on a richer interface.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, that refers to individual pages served up depending on whether the client has javascript enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Because whoever wrote it thought that "javascript" was an appropriate class name for it to have? I mean, it's not an invalid class name...

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are referring to a CSS class to control the formatting, and its name is irrelevant.

Something like:

> <span class='javascript'>a = 3 * 5;</span>

Could just as easily be:

> <span class='Ben'>a = 3 * 5;</span>

Naming it 'Ben' may not be as good of a reminder when editing the CSS file for what the desired formatting is.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it was code in the page that was to be displayed using Javascript syntax highlighting?

```
<code class="javascript">document.write("Ben rules!")</code>
```